# Почему возвращается None вместо текста в верхнем регистре?

Tags: python, функции, декоратор

```py
text = 'this is a sentence'

def upper_text(funk):
    def wrapper(text):
        funk(text.upper())
    return wrapper

@upper_text
def function(text):
    return text

print(function(text))
```

Comment: Вообще это элементарное правило питона: если возвращается `None`, значит вы ничего не вернули из функции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что результат функции тоже нужно возвращать:

```py
def upper_text(funk):
    def wrapper(text):
        return funk(text.upper())
#       ^^^^^^
    return wrapper
```